# ¿Cómo puedo conectarme a SQL Server a tavés de Node.js desde una VPS?

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, vps

Tengo problemas para conectarme desde mi aplicación desarrollada con *Node.js* con el modulo `mssql` a una base de datos administrada por el gestor de *SQL Server* desde una *VPS*.

El problema es, que cuando intento conectarme desde *Node.js* me arroja un mensaje que dice: `Login failed for user '********'`, donde estoy poniendo bien el `pass` y el `usuario`. Incluso me puedo conectar desde *Management*  desde mi *PC* y desde la *VPS*.

El sistema de mi VPS es Windows Server 2016.

Comment: encontraste una solucion? tengo el mismo problema :(

Comment: Probaste usando "sequelize" ? http://docs.sequelizejs.com/

Comment: Lo solucione, simplemente actualizando "tedious" dentro de la libreria MSSQL